# Tailwind does not apply custom font family in production build

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, tailwind-css

I am using Vue with Tailwind right now.

Here is my current Tailwind config:

```js
const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme');

module.exports = {
  purge: [],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        sans: ['Inter var', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
      },
    },
  },
  variants: {},
  plugins: [],
}
```

I am using the `Inter var` font, because on OSX systems the default font weights do not work. Right now, I want to build this project, but in the production version it does not apply the correct font family. I've tried to import the font family via a html link and css import, but neither of those worked.

Comment: Where did you import this font file/typeface?

Comment: For development it is on my computer. But I've tried to import the font through a html link in the index.html file and a css import in the tailwind css file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on Vue-CLI, I'd recommend adding [the typeface](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typeface-inter) via NPM for maintainability, and import it into your entry file (e.g. `main.js`). This package will take care of referencing and importing the webfont(s) for you, so there's no need to create additional CSS anymore.

### Installing the font

```
npm i typeface-inter
```

### Importing it

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import 'typeface-inter';
// ...
```

And of course, you'll still need to [extend the font-family](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/theme/#referencing-the-default-theme) (or simply adding it to the list will work too).

Comment: Still doesn't work. I've tried to import another font, but the issue is still there.

Comment: How are you currently confirming if the desired font isn't applied? I'm assuming you know that it will only fallback to _the_ font if the others are not present/installed on the machine.

Comment: It might be worth a try to add this font to the collection rather than extending it, and then explicitly target this particular font and apply it to certain element.

Comment: That's weird. I've created a extra collection and only specified Inter, applied the class and this works fine.

Comment: @FloWy You should be able to specify multiple fonts alongside it, as long as it's the "first applicable" one  within the font families, it should really work.

Comment: It's all about [selection priority by the browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-family), based on installed fonts in the list.

Comment: It was a problem with PostCSS. Everything was good. Anyway, thank you!